# Usage of 74LVC1T45 in open-drain case

Tags: digital-logic, interface, logic-level, open-drain

I want to do one 'universal' or 'multiprotocol'-capable IO block and currently **thinking of using 74LVC1T45 level translator** to do the communication between two different voltage leveled systems.

I would want to be able to support UART, I2C and any other custom serial that works in a similar manner. So the B side can be push-pull, open drain, with and without pull-ups/-downs...

**The hard part to grasp is how to accommodate a certain open-drain use-case where the interface-d system (B) might NOT have their pull-up mounted...**
What should I add/consider when doing the circuit...

How I imagine it, is that for such open-drain use case:

B to A:

A (receiver) side  has to have pull-up(s) enabled. The B side doesn't have a pull-up (*for whatever reason*).

When B transmits LOW, the A side is also pulled low.
When B wants to transmit High - meaning that B is a float (even though the currently non-existent-pullup should otherwise pull the line high), **the 74LVC has no way to pull the A line high ?** 
Basically, when floating B doesn't go over a threshold of VCCI× 0.65 (so for 1.8V Vih>1.17V), **I cannot assume that when B is a float, the A can go to High ?**

1) **Does, in that case, the B really is isolated from port A ?** and I need to add my own pull-up for the B side ?
(as I understand, from A to B direction and open-drain use-case I could get away with the no pull-up on the B side, as when A is high, the B is also pulled high).

**or how could I understand it better ?**
*(I have only found a IBIS model(s) for that part, but no idea how to use that).*

Circuit as requested:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjvpWb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

2) Aha also, remembered:
In case of **bidirectional** serial - in that case I2C, the datasheet mentioned that 'the designer must bear in mind that the bus won't get contention when DIR is flipped". 
**So does this mean that in order to change the DIR, I must first remove either VCCA or VCCB (thus 'disable' the device), change the DIR, enable VCCa or VCCB again, and only then start sending/receiving ?**

Assumptions are:

- Main MCU is @1.8VccA and the expected maximum interface line is @5VccB
- The expected load on the output line B, when trying to pull High, can be max 1k.
  (I've read the 74LVC to be specced with 2k load - that's actually good enough for me).
- With Output as an open-drain transmitter, **the transmitter (B) might not have their pull-up implemented.**

Comment: Please create a schematic for the specific circuit you are asking about.

Comment: @CL. added the schematic - the built-in one was not perfect, so some of the 'block' objects are missing or a bit dispositioned, but on the lefthand MCU GPIO's there should be internal pull-up/-down shown as well.

Answer (score 0):

When an open-drain signal is inactive without a pull-up resistor, then the B input is floating. This is an invalid state; the input might be read as low, or high, or oscillating, and you might get shoot-through currents (see [TI's FAQ](https://e2e.ti.com/support/logic/f/151/t/737694)).

Furthermore, I²C is a bidirectional bus, and there are times when it is not possible to determine a direction (when no or multiple drivers are active). So it is not possible to use a direction-controlled level shifter like the 74LVC1T45 for I²C; this requires a passive switch like the LSF0101 (or a plain MOSFET).

If you want to be able to switch between UART and I²C, you need both kind of level shifters, and additional switches to connect them appropriately.